# Creating a custom control for Lightswitch

Tags: c#, visual-studio-lightswitch

I need to create a custom control that is basically a WPF StackPanel with some TextBoxes to filter a table in the data source of my project.

This custom control will be used only by this application.

Do I need to create a Lightswitch extension project or there's another way to do this having into account that the custom control will be used only by this project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you don't need to create an extension project in that case.

Check this tutorial [Create a custom control in a Lightswitch application](http://geekswithblogs.net/ebartolesi/archive/2011/08/08/create-a-custom-control-in-a-lightswitch-application.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

To add a custom control to a screen

1. In the Screen Content Tree, select any group.
2. At the top of the Screen Designer, click Add Layout Item and then click Custom Control.
3. In the Add Custom Control dialog box, expand the assembly node, expand the namespace node, and then select the control node.
4. If the assembly that you want does not appear in the Add Custom Control dialog box, click Add Reference. In the Add Reference dialog box, select an assembly or local project that contains the control that you want to use, and then click OK.
5. In the Specify the data for the new custom control field, type the name of the screen data that you want to bind to the control, and then click OK.
   For example, if you want a custom list box to show names from a collection named CustomerSet, type CustomerSet. If you want the control to show the name of the currently selected customer, type CustomerSet.SelectedItem.ContactName.

Refer: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg406736.aspx